# AWS Copilot pipeline fails, why cant CodeBuild find buildspec.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-copilot

I created an aws Copilot pipeline but it fails because CodeBuild says it can't find `buildspec.yml`.

[image: CodeBuild can't find buildspec.yml]

I'm not sure where the beginning of the path comes from `/codebuild/output/src1#####3/src/` however the second part of the path is exactly correct `/copilot/pipelines/projectname-master/buildspec.yml`

[image: buildspec.yml exists]

How can I troubleshoot why this file cannot be found?

Note: this was set up using the `copilot pipeline init` cli command

Comment: Where did you run `copilot pipeline init`? In the root or the `src` folder?

Comment: I've tried it both ways.  it seems to me CodeBuild is expecting it in /src/ but that doesn't update no matter where i create the pipeline from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is related to a bug surfaced here: https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/3468, which has been fixed with https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/pull/3532 and released just this morning – please update Copilot to v1.18.0.